# Raspberry pi how to use subprocess and espeak

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, subprocess, espeak

I am now finding ways of how to announce a sentence using espeak. When I am in the terminal, when I type

```
espeak -s 5 "where are you" --stdout | aplay
```

it comes out this

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ espeak -s 5 "where are you" --stdout | aplay
Playing WAVE 'stdin' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 22050 Hz, Mono
```

then if i remove the `--stdout | aplay` it becomes:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ espeak -s 5 "where are you"
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.front
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround40
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround41
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround50
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround51
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround71
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.iec958
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.iec958
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.iec958
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:957:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) The dmix plugin supports only playback stream
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
```

Then, I realised that in order to run this in a python file , I have to use the `subprocess.call()` function

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["espeak", "-s 5 -ven", "where are you"])
```

This code above is OK. But when I use the below code, is like hell breaks loose, and many strange characters appear continuously on my screen.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["espeak", "-s 5 -ven", "where are you", "--stdout", "|", "aplay"])
```

The first question is what does `--stdout | aplay` means actually?
Then, how to put it in subprocess.call, so it will work? The reason is without --stdout | aplay, the voice seems to lag/stutter/broken when the sentence are longer.

Comment: The pipe `|` is a shell feature. Try `subprocess.call(..., shell=True)`.

Comment: I tried:    subprocess.call(["espeak", "-s 5 -ven", "where are you", "--stdout", "shell=True", "aplay"])  and the result is the same, many strange characters on the screen. It is as if the sound is output in text format, but no sound audible.

Comment: That's not how you use `shell=True`. That should be `subprocess.call('espeak -s 5 "where are you" --stdout | aplay', shell=True)`

Comment: @Rawing, Thank you very much! Really!